# How to markup with Microdata a "table of contents" and "embedded content" for a PublicationIssue?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, iframe

Suppose I have a [`PublicationIssue`](http://schema.org/PublicationIssue) of a Periodical, and I display a webpage with a ToC/summary with a list of [`Article`s](https://schema.org/Article) and a file document embedded with an `iframe`. The issue content is *not* coded on the page directly, but is fully available as file embedded.

For example, consider the following simplified HTML:

```html
<article>
    <h1>Issue number 42</h1>

    <div class="toc">
        Table of contents:
        <ul>
            <li>Editorial</li>
            <li>First article</li>
            <li>Another interesting article</li>
            <li>The importance of microdata</li>
            <li>Microtagging your ToC like a pro</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- here we have an embed document via iframe like a PDF or maybe a google doc or similar  -->
    <iframe src="url-to-file-embed"></iframe>
</article>
```

How can you markup the above with structured data so that you can inform crawlers that the `ul` is the ToC of the issue with the relative articles and the content of the issue is actually the `src` of the `iframe` embed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `iframe`, Microdata will use the `src` value as property value. So you can specify `itemprop="url"` on the `iframe` to convey that this file *is* the [`PublicationIssue`](https://schema.org/PublicationIssue).

There doesn’t seem to be a property for a ToC, though. You could use [`hasPart`](https://schema.org/hasPart) to provide each `Article`, even if you only provide a `name` per `Article`. If the file allows linking to specific parts/pages, you could provide each article’s link in a `link` element; if it doesn’t, I would simply omit the `url` property.

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PublicationIssue">

  <ul>

    <li itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
      <span itemprop="name">First article</span>
      <link itemprop="url" href="url-to-file-embed#page-2" /> <!-- omit if there is no such URL --> 
    </li>

    <li itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
      <span itemprop="name">Another interesting article</span>
      <link itemprop="url" href="url-to-file-embed#page-4" /> <!-- omit if there is no such URL --> 
    </li>

  </ul>

  <iframe itemprop="url" src="url-to-file-embed"></iframe>

</article>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll leave the discussion open for a bit longer, but your answer is indeed a nice approach, if nothing else is suggested I will accept and follow it.